# Excel 2013 - Macro shortcuts do not work properly, but the macro works fine by active it manually

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script to copy data from current file to another workbook. If I run it manually, the code works well. It copies data from the current workbook, then opens another one, paste data and finally close it.

However, If I run this macro by Shortcuts, it just pastes the data and does not close the target workbook.

```
Sub CopyToBMD()
'
' CopyToBMD Macro
' Copy Lastest BMD price to appropriate day in the table
'
'
Dim target As Integer
Dim LDate As String

Sheets(1).Select
Range("B48:R48").Copy

LDate = Date

If Cells(40, 2).Value = Cells(1, 2).Value Then
    target = 2
Else
    target = 8
End If

' Paste data to BMD&CBOT
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim folderPath As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Find file location
folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
FilePath = Dir(folderPath & "\BMD&CBOT.xlsx")

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & FilePath)
Set ws = wbk.Sheets("CPO-Jun 16")

' i is the row number
Dim i As Integer

For i = 4 To 34
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = LDate Then
        ws.Cells(i, target).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
Next i

wbk.Close True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
[your code]
    End If
Next i
debug.print wbk.name
wbk.Close True

End Sub
```

What does it print? In short - do not use "ActiveWorkbook", but refer it explicitly, as you have done with wbk.